# one to one mapping in shell script

Tags: python, shell, unix, conditional-statements

I am in process of migration. Migrating from old set of servers to new set of servers, where there is no logical relationship in the server names between the 2 sets. 
     I have a script that runs on old server, takes all necessary backups and the run another script to copy the backups to new server and execute it.

I can combine both scripts(taking backup and copying to new server), if I can include a logic to map the old server to new server. Is there a way I can do this.

```
Old server   New server

King          Queen
Bat           Ball
water         fire
sand          rock
```

What I am expecting is, if the script is run on server 'King', I want the script to identify that the corresponding new server is 'Queen' and copy the backups to Queen.

Comment: ...okay, that's what you want to do; what's the specific question about bash-the-language you encountered while trying to do it?

Comment: If the question is just "how do I store this mapping?", that's wide open -- heck, you could have a directory where each file is an old hostname and its contents are the new hostname; or you could have an [associative array](http://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays#associative_bash_4) where the keys are the old names and the values are the new ones; or you could have a prefixed variable namespace doing the same; or... well, the number of possible approaches are endless; there's no real *specificity* here.

Comment: I am looking for something to start with to put in this condition/mapping within the script. like if I need to use an array within the script or use separate awk script to do the substitutions for old and new servers

Comment: There are a nearly infinite number of ways to approach this. Can you provide a sample of some code you have tried? Also, you tagged this both `python` and `shell`. Which is it? The two languages are not very similar.

Comment: For one way to start, in a shell script, create a function that given a name will return the new name. In that function, write a single case statement that returns the correct name for a matching input.

Comment: I am flexible using either pythin or the shell though more comfortable with shell

Answer (score 2):

Using bash associative arrays:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
declare -A renames=( [King]=Queen [Bat]=Ball [water]=fire [sand]=rock )
hostname=$(hostname)

if [[ ${renames[$hostname]} ]]; then
  echo "The current host, $hostname, is being renamed to ${renames[$hostname]}"
fi
```

Or with a simple function running a case statement, thus compatible with *all* POSIX shells:

```
newName() {
  case $1 in
    King)  echo "Queen" ;;
    Bat)   echo "Ball" ;;
    water) echo "fire" ;;
    sand)  echo "rock" ;;
    *)     return 1 ;;
  esac
}

if dest=$(newName "$hostname"); then
  echo "Name $hostname is being renamed to $dest"
fi
```

Or with a series of prefixed variables:

```
rename_King=Queen
rename_Bat=Ball
rename_water=fire
rename_sand=rock

var="rename_$hostname"
if [[ ${!var} ]]; then
  echo "$hostname is being renamed to ${!var}"
fi
```

Or with a directory:

```
renameDir=/path/to/renames
if [[ -e "$renameDir/$hostname" ]]; then
  echo "Renaming $host to $(<"$renameDir/$hostname")"
fi
```

Or scanning a file and finding the first match:

```
if dest=$(awk -v search="$hostname" '$1 == search { print $2; exit; }' <input) && [[ $dest ]]; then
  echo "Renaming $hostname to $dest"
fi
```

...or so on, or so forth.

Comment: Can I read it from a input file(with 2 coloumns)  during declaration

Comment: Sure. Should have put that in the question if it's what you wanted. (I'm off to lunch, though, so won't be amending this for a bit).

Comment: I can use the case statement, since I have used it ., but since these are more than 50 servers, I will explore how to use the case statement from a input file. Thank you!

Comment: @MO12 The format of that input file would have been a valuable part of your question.

Comment: @BenjaminW. It is the same format I mentioned in the original question

Comment: ...as in, you want it to have a *header*? That's extra complexity, and for what purpose?

Comment: @MO12, ...that said, I added an example using awk to scan your file with a textual table.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy no header required. Thank you